# Combining TEXT and YEAR returns odd result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

In cell A1 I have this date and time: `2022-01-01 16:00`

If I do this `=Year(A1)-1` the result is as expected `2021`

If I do this `=TEXT((Year(A1)-1), "YY")` the answer is `05`

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web application are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2022 is not a date. It is a number that you extracted from a date.

If you want to save the last 2 digits of the year

```
A1 = '2022-01-01 16:00'

=RIGHT(YEAR(A1)-1),2)
=21
```

If you want apply date formatting you will need to apply it to a date.

```
A1 = '2022-01-01 16:00'

=TEXT(EDATE(A1,-12),"yy") 
=21
```

##### Serialized Dates

In order to understand why `TEXT(2021, "yy") = 05` you need to know that, at its core, Sheets stores dates as serialized numbers, and uses the 1900 date system.

- Today's date, `October 28, 2022` is stored as `44,862`
- `July 13, 1905`, is stored as `2021`

It now becomes easy to see why pulling the year from the date `2021` would give you `05` or `1905` depending how you formatted it.

**How to Test Numbers**
You can use the function `TO_DATE(value)` to test any number for the associated date.

**Math**
Adding (/subtracting) whole numbers from a serialized date is equivalent to adding (/subtracting) days.  Fractions of days will be displayed as time if number is formatted to display time.

**Example**
Custom Number Format: "m/d/yyyy H:mm:ss (ms "ms")
`to_date(44,147.05) = 11/12/2020 1:12:00 (120 ms)`

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this formula and, from the result, you will understand why that result happened (05):

```
=TEXT( 2021 , "dd mmm yy")
```